# Determine current Firestore mode

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

We are setting up a new project/environment in Google Cloud for our application. The applications uses Firestore which is being setup in the new project.

How do you determine which Firestore mode the current Firstore is running in?

When you navigate to Firestore in a new project you are presented with an option, select Firestore mode, Native Mode or Datastore Mode. The goal is to ensure the new environment being setup is the same as the current one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Firestore]
[image: Datastore]

When you check the Firestore in the Google Cloud Console Navigation menu, you will see **Firestore** for Native Mode (Firestore API), and **Datastore** for Datastore Mode (Datastore API).

Comment: I cannot confirm this. I added a new project and created a native Firestore. The Google Cloud Console only reads "Firestore", there is nothing indicating "native mode"

Comment: I created two projects with Firestore. The Google Cloud Console reads Firestore for Native mode ( project1) and Datastore for Datastore Mode(project2)

Comment: Where do you see this exactly? Perhaps I am looking in the wrong places

Comment: Clear as mud Google. Thank you [marian.vladoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11928099/marian-vladoi)!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer above, if you'd like to check this using **Cloud SDK** via command line you can

1. use `gcloud firestore databases list` and look for the `type` parameter
2. use `gcloud firestore databases list --format="value(type)"` which will output the type directly

[image: screenshot of using gcloud firestore databases list command]